# Regex to select text outside of underscores

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex to select the text which falls outside of underscore characters.

Sample text:

```
PartIWant_partINeedIgnored_morePartsINeedIgnored_PartIwant
```

Basically I need to be able to select the first keyword which is always before the first underscore and the last keyword which is always after the last underscore. As an additional complexity, there case also be texts which have no underscore at all, these need to be selected completely as well.

The best I got yet was this expression:

```
^((?! *\_[^)]*\_ *).)*
```

which is only yielding me the first part, not the second and it has no support for the non-underscore yet at all.

This regex is used in a tool which monitors our http traffic, which means I can only 'select' the part I need but can't invoke functions or replace logic.

Thanks!

Comment: See [`^([^_]*)(?:.*_([^_]*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/YcjWDD/1).

Comment: Can you do a substitute of nothing for `_.*_` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
/(^[^_]+)|([^_]+$)/g
```

That is, match either:

- `^[^_]+` the beginning of the string followed by non-underscores, or
- `[^_]+$` non-underscores followed by the end of the string.

```js
var regex = /(^[^_]+)|([^_]+$)/g

console.log("A_b_c_D".match(regex))   // ["A", "D"]
console.log("A_b_D".match(regex))     // ["A", "D"]
console.log("A_D".match(regex))       // ["A", "D"]
console.log("AD".match(regex))        // ["AD"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript string function `split()`. Check below example.

```js
var t = "PartIWant_partINeedIgnored_morePartsINeedIgnored_PartIwant";
var arr = t.split('_');

console.log(arr);

//Access the required parts like this
console.log(arr[0] + ' ' + arr[arr.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I can sadly not use JS functions given the context I am in. Updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you should use a regex here. I think splitting the string at underscore, and using the first and last element of the resulting array might be faster, and less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial with `.replace`:

```
str.replace(/_.*_/, '')
// "PartIWantPartIwant"
```

With matching, you'd need to be selecting and concatenating groups:

```
parts = str.match(/^([^_]*).*?([^_]*)$/)
parts[1] + parts[2]
// "PartIWantPartIwant"
```

**EDIT**

> This regex is used in a tool which monitors our http traffic, which means I can only 'select' the part I need but can't invoke functions or replace logic.

This is not possible: a regular expression cannot match a discontinuous span.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I can sadly not use JS functions given the context I am in. Updated my question to reflect this.